# Event when Markers are loaded

Tags: javascript, performance, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have 25k markers that are added to a Google Map object. The problem is that process is very slow (even using markerClusters). Takes like 15 secs to load them to the map (the js code finishes executing in 2 secs, but it takes extra 15 secs aprox to show the markers in the map).
I want to add a spinner till it finishes loading all the markers. Do you know any event that fires when the map is changed? or something like that. 
I tried with the events on the doc with no luck.

```
function loadPlaces(places, defaultOptions, clusterizarMarkers, clusterStyles) {
    locations = [];
    markers = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {

        var unPlace = places[i];
        transformPlace(unPlace);
        unPlace.colorLabelAlerta = getColorPorTipoDeCentro(unPlace.tipoCentro);
        (function () {
            function createMarkerOptions(place, clusterizarMarkers) {
                var posicion = new google.maps.LatLng(place.lat, place.lng);
                var markerOptions = {
                    position: posicion,
                    title: place.name
                };
                if (!clusterizarMarkers) {
                    markerOptions.map = map;
                }

                return markerOptions;
            }

            var location = {};
            location.place = unPlace;
            location.place.id = i;
            location.marker = new google.maps.Marker(createMarkerOptions(unPlace, clusterizarMarkers));
            markers.push(location.marker);
            var icon;
            if (unPlace.tipoCentro === "Centro 4G" && unPlace.diametro && unPlace.diametro > 0) {
                icon = "/myplaces-portlet/img/transparente.png";
            } else if (defaultOptions.iconGenerator) {
                icon = defaultOptions.iconGenerator(unPlace);
            } else if (unPlace.mapIcon) {
                icon = unPlace.mapIcon;
            }

            var iconImage = new Image();
            iconImage.src = icon;

            iconImage.onload = function () {
                location.marker.setIcon(icon);
            };
            iconImage.onerror = function () {
                location.marker.setIcon(defaultOptions.defaultIcon);
            };
            locations.push(location);

            google.maps.event.addListener(location.marker, 'click', function () {
                myplaces.util.ui.places.selecteById(location.place.id);
            });
        })();

        if (unPlace.tipoCentro === "Centro 4G" && unPlace.diametro && unPlace.diametro > 0) {
            //diametro 
            var populationOptions = {
                strokeColor: '#79B800',
                strokeOpacity: 0.6,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                fillColor: '#79B800',
                fillOpacity: 0.25,
                map: map,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(unPlace.lat, unPlace.lng),
                //radius: Math.sqrt(antenas4g[antena].population) * 100
                radius: unPlace.diametro / 2
            };
            antenaArea = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
            unPlace.circulo = antenaArea;
        }
    }
    if (clusterizarMarkers && markers.length) {
        // var mcOptions = {gridSize: 30, maxZoom: 15};
        var mcOptions = {
            styles: clusterStyles
        };
        mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is taking 15 seconds, getting the markers from your storage or actually adding them to the map? Also how are you adding them to the map. Post some example code and we may be able to help

Comment: also tried console.time() to take the time of the function, and it finishes in 200 ms

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm experiencing the same issue.